# React Native App is not installing in ios simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, react-native

I am using ios simulator but my app is not installing on it i am using Visual Studio Code to run my app using this command... 
react-native run-ios
but i my app is not installing just showing this screen please have a look at this image an suggest any answer[image]

Comment: it seems like it still loading. Have in mind that first time on the simulator it will get more time. Because it should start the simulator and also it should package react native app which is around some hundreds of MBs.

Comment: @m1sh0 it is just completed and build failed with this error
linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: can you show me some stack trace?

Comment: Check your project and manually unlink the packages indicated using `react-native unlink <module>`

Comment: @codekaizer let me check it

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to manual linking of the packages. React-native version 0.60 and above 0.60 version supports auto-linking. Your react-native version is 0.60.4 and you are running **react-native link** or manual linking. Don't run react-native link or manual linking for 0.60 and above version. **Run react-native unlink and then run the the command react-native run-ios**. It will work